# I am unable to install the Dapr in Ubuntu terminal using Oracle Virtual Box

Tags: docker, publish-subscribe, dapr

```
manish@manish:~$ wget -q https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dapr/cli/master/install/install.sh -O - | /bin/bash
manish@manish:~$ wget -q https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dapr/cli/master/install/install.sh -O - | /bin/bash
manish@manish:~$ wget -q https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dapr/cli/master/install/install.sh -O - | /bin/bash
manish@manish:~$
```

I used this Linux command to download the Dapr from official website [https://docs.dapr.io/getting-started/install-dapr-cli/](https://stackoverflow.com)

```
wget -q https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dapr/cli/master/install/install.sh -O - | /bin/bash
```

I am unable to download `Dapr` in my `Ubuntu Virtual Box`. I'm unable to see the downloading process when I use to download

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4REn.png)

I am just trying to download Dapr to start with micro services along with Docker. But I installed docker in my Ubuntu.